# AWK: search substring in first file against second

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the following files:

`data.txt`

```
Estring|0006|this_is_some_random_text|more_text
Fstring|0010|random_combination_of_characters
Fstring|0028|again_here
```

`allids.txt` (here the columns are separated by semicolon; the real input is **tab-delimited**)

```
Estring|0006;MAR0593
Fstring|0002;MAR0592
Fstring|0028;MAR1195
```

please note: `data.txt`: the important part is here the first two "columns" = `name|number`)

Now I want to use `awk` to search the first part (`name|number`) of `data.txt` in `allids.txt` and output the second column (starting with `MAR`)

so my expected output would be (again tab-delimited):

```
Estring|0006|this_is_some_random_text|more_text;MAR0593
Fstring|0010|random_combination_of_characters
Fstring|0028|again_here;MAR1195
```

I do not know now how to search that first conserved part within awk, the rest should then be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$1] = $1; next } $1 in a { print a[$0], [$1] }' data.txt allids.txt
```

Comment: thanks, @hek2mgl, for correcting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a set of field delimiters, like this:

```
awk -F'[|\t;]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1"|"$2]=$0; next}
                $1"|"$2 in a {print a[$1"|"$2]"\t"$NF}' data.txt allids.txt
```

In your *real-data* example you can remove the `;`. It is in here just to be able to reproduce the example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `awk` that uses a different field separator for both files:

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=FS $2; next} {k=$1 FS $2} 
    k in a{$0=$0 a[k]} 1' allids.txt FS='|' data.txt

Estring|0006|this_is_some_random_text|more_text;MAR0593
Fstring|0010|random_combination_of_characters
Fstring|0028|again_here;MAR1195
```

This command uses `;` as FS for `allids.txt` and uses `|` as FS for `data.txt`.